# Azure Service bus messaging

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I want to connect a windows phone 8.1 application to my raspberry pi running windows IoT (UWP). I wanted to know how can I implement a azure service bus to transfer data from my phone to windows IoT. I found [this documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/#create-a-queue)
but I can't seem to install the nugget package. Am I following the wrong documentation? I need help. Thanks

Comment: if you have visual studio 2013, did you upgrade your visual studio by update 5 ? (I upgraded my visual studio to use this package (Azure))

Comment: @h.o.m.a.n I am using visual studio 15 enterprise

Comment: What you mean by "can't seem to install the nugget package"? Is there any error message? This package's name is now "WindowsAzure.ServiceBus", I just tried to install this package of version 3.1.6 in a windows phone 8.1 project, it succeed.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT it gives me an error saying package installation failed     and nothing else. I was wondering if you could help me out by giving me a documentation or a git hub sample about sending messages from windows phone 8.1 application to a windows 10 UWP running on windows IoT core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, your needs is that sending messages from Windows Phone and receiving them on Respberry Pi device, and message transpose via a message queue service like Azure Service Bus. It's an IoT project.

As I known, Azure support IoT via Azure IoTHub service. It's the offical recommend way for IoT project.

So for helping you get start with IoTHub, please follow the steps below.

1. Setup an IoTHub service on Azure, please see the doc [Get started with Azure IoT Hub for .NET](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted/)
2. For sending messages from Windows Phone, I think you can try to follow [the blog](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/03/connect-your-windows-app-to-azure-iot-hub-with-visual-studio/) to connect the IoTHub service and send messages. The other way is using the REST API for [sending device-to-cloud message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt590784.aspx) to IoTHub via HttpClient, you can refer to [the UWP sample for HttpClient](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HttpClient)  and the [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-rm-rest/#complete-and-run-the-application) to do it.
3. For receiving messges on Raspberry Pi device, there is an offical sample code using IoTHub SDK for device you can refer to, please see https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/doc/get_started/windows10-iotcore-csharp.md.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.